# Detect SSD/HDD from Bash Script

Tags: ssd, bash, hdd

Is it possible to check if a file path points to a ssd or hdd?

For example a script could do more operations in parallel when running on a SSD while on a HDD it would hurt performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
diskutil info "$(df /path/to/file | sed -n '2s|^.*% */|/|p')" | awk '/Solid State/ {print $NF}'
```

Returns `Yes` if solid state, `No` if not, and `Info not available` otherwise.

---

- subshell `df /file/path | awk 'NR==2{print $NF}'`

  `df /path/to/file` prints information on the mount point containing the given file.
  `sed` replaces in the result.
  `-n` disables ‘automatic’ printing, i.e. only print lines that have been specifically told to print.
  `2` performs the operation on the second line.
  `s|` performs a substitution with the arguments between occurrences of the delimiter given.
  `^` from the start of the line.
  `.*%` any characters any number of times, up to the last percent sign.
   `*/` then any number of spaces before the slash.
  `|/` should be replaced with a slash.
  `|p` and the line should be printed.

  This returns something like `/Volumes/MyVolumeName`.
- command `diskutil info /Volumes/MyVolumeName | awk '/Solid State/ {print $NF}'`

  `diskutil info` provides information about the disk or volume given.
  `awk` filters on the result.
  `/Solid State/` returns lines containing the string "Solid State".
  `{print $NF}` prints the last column.

---

Example: my home directory is on the internal SSD which is solid state, command returns "Yes".

```
$ diskutil info "$(df ~ | sed -n '2s|^.*% */|/|p')" | awk '/Solid State/ {print $NF}'
Yes
```

Comment: I have an external drive called "Mobile TM", `awk 'NR==2{print $NF}')` doesn't work there. Using `diskutil info "$(df /path/to/file | sed -n '2s|^.*% */|/|p')"` would solve that, but the `Solid State:               Info not available` output I get for the drive is more difficult to handle :-)

Comment: @nohillside Thanks, edited answer with that